# How to create a background like Dribbble.com?

Tags: background

I'm curious about the background of http://dribbble.com/ . I've seen something similar on a couple of other sites too.

What's it called?

How can I create something like with a different color?

Thanks for any pointers. I'm a non-designer trying to learn some design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Both header and body part having gradient and inner shadow with some amount of noise. Play with sliders and you'll get the same result. I tried a bit just to show you; change values according to your needs...

Answer (score 1):

It's called grey.

But if you're talking about the header, it looks like it's a vertical gradient with either gaussian noise or another gradient overlaid with a layer style of "Dissolve"

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the background for the majority of the page, it's a linear gradient from white at the top to light grey at the bottom, and any graphics application will have a gradient fill tool which will interpolate between two or more colours.

Exactly how it works is dependent on the application.

(The other answers mention noise, which is interesting, as I can't differentiate it at all on my screen from the "background noise" of video compression - I'm remotely accessing a VM)