# how to get that new JSFIDDLE/Twitter/Youtube effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, effects

As all the big sites have been updating their style recently, I've noticed this effect on a few sites and I'm wondering how they do it.

Its like this normal gradient effect, with this pattern, abbit similar to a dissolving effect, but not quite that...

JSFIDDLE:
Its on the top menu bar on this site: http://jsfiddle.net

Twitter:
Again, its on the top black menu bar on http://twitter.com.

Youtube:
Its like the whole of Youtube's background but its quite hard to notice on that one. http://youtube.com

Do you guys see what I'm talking about?

How would I get that effect in Photoshop?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a background like Dribbble.com?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/how-to-create-a-background-like-dribbble-com)

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/what-is-this-pattern-called-and-how-is-it-created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called 'noise'. Most raster image editing software have various noise filters.

Answer (score 4):

Actually in JsFiddle I've used a combination of noise and a very subtle grain texture.

Comment: Lol at that :) (+1)

Comment: Glad you did :)

Answer (score 0):

The art here is to use a pattern on top of your chosen color, and then lowering down the opacity of your pattern overlay to an almost imperceptible level. An example is here:
[image]

(I've used the 'Parchment' pattern with 20% opacity)